# How much a variable contributed to the result of some cost function

Tags: calculus, analysis, summation, multiplicative-function

I have this simple cost function: $\sum_{i=1}^n d_i\times h_i \times a_i$

I wanted to analyze, for example, how much the $a$ component/variable contributed to the final cost function. In other words, i'm looking for some expression that tells me if the $a$ variable produced a big impact in the final cost or not.

What is the best and most straighforward way to achieve this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just a suggestion but how about compare the cost function with a's in against one calculated with every $a=1$.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my question:

$C_d = \sum_{i=1}^n d_i$

$C_h = \sum_{i=1}^n (d_i \times h_i  - di)$

$C_a = \sum_{i=1}^n (d_i \times h_i \times a_i - d_i \times h_i)$

$C_t = C_d + C_h + C_a$